# How to call WebPage in folder from another WebPage in a folder

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I am working in VS2010 ASP.NET, I decided to move some of my pages in folders and they reference pages in other folders. When I run in virtual debug mode in VS it runs ok, but when I deploy it on the host server the pages cannot see each other. i tried using ../FolderName/Webpage.aspx, ~/FolderName/Webpage.aspx and still no avail.

However if I have a webpage that is not in a folder and then reference a page in a folder it works fine. Anyone else have this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to use `ResolveUrl` to reference all resources such as javascript files, css files, etc.

For example:

```
<script src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/Javascript/datables-extensions.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

As far as pages referencing other pages, you should be able to use the relative path (`../Folder/other_page.aspx`) without any problems. Don't use absolute paths or your website will have issues like you describe when you deploy to a different environment that has a different folder structure.

Comment: @lcarus Thank you. Will resolveUrl aslo work for a usercontrol reference at the top of the page? I was also getting the MagicAjax error too. I think it was because it couldn't find the path.

Comment: @tszoro: I don't think it's necessary to do that for a control. You can just simply drag and drop it onto your page. Visual Studio will add the right relative path for you. In general, just use relative paths to reference pages/controls. ResolveUrl is best for referencing javascript/css files.

Comment: @lcarus how about the web.config file? <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>

Comment: @tszoro: No, you can't use ResolveUrl inside Web.config. ResolveUrl is a method inherited from `Control`. Use the relative path as you are doing now.

Comment: @lcarus How would I resolve a user control when i Register on top of page? I tried but get error. <%@ Register Src="../UserControls/BomItem.ascx" TagName="BomItem" TagPrefix="uc1" %>

Comment: @tszoro: drag and drop the control inside your page, that's the best way to have the register part automatically added for you with the right relative path.